# Tasks are Deleting but the page needs to be refereshed

Tags: php, laravel-5, vuejs2

Every time I make some tasks Deleted nothing happens but when I refreshed the page tasks are deleted

This is mine Pug Code

```
button.btn.btn-danger.float-right#delete(v-on:click="delete_event(client_id,id)" type="button" style="margin-left:10px;")
                            i.fa.fa-trash(style="font-size:20px; color:whitesmoke;")
```

This is mine Vue.js Function

```
   delete_event:function(){

                this.loading=true;
                let url='/clients/' + this.client_id + '/events/' + this.event.id;
                this.$http.delete(url).then(res=>{
                if(res.data.errcode == 1){
                    this.$root.$refs.toastr.e(res.data.errmess,this.$t("template.Error"));
                }else{
                     this.$root.$refs.toastr.s(this.$t("client.Task_deleted"),this.$t("template.Success"));
               }      
               this.loading=false;
                },res=>{
                   this.$root.$refs.toastr.e(this.$t("template.Server_error").this.$t("template.Error"));
                   this.loading=false;
                });
           }
```

This is mine Controller

```
public function delete_event(Request $request,$client_id,$id){
        return response()->json(Event::destroy($id),200);

}
```

Comment: Please show your component data. What should be deleted from it?

Comment: it's not clear how your component displays the data. Obviously the delete request works fine, since the refresh show the changed data, so the issue is with updating the current state.